# passing web url as parameter in web service using wcf in c#

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

[image: When I am Sending the Object from Angularjs I am getting "GET" verb Instead of "POST"][image: This is the error I am getting After submitting the data]Here I want to pass Video url as parameter in my Restful web service using WCF. I have Video url Column in a table. While inserting data I want to insert video url too. In web service I am sending the video url as parameter. The problem is that, While passing parameter video url consist of "\" or "/". Because of these symbols I am not able to insert data through web service. Please suggest me how to escape "\" or "/" symbols or other way to pass video url as parameter in restful web service.

```
[OperationContract()] 
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddPOI/{POICTG}/{Name}/{Description}/{BestTimetoVisit}/{TimeFrom}/{TimeTo}/{Add‌​ress}/{Contact_No}/{Lattitude}/{Longitude}/{Altitude}/{Accuracy}/{Image}/{Video_U‌​RL}/{Active_Inactive_Flag}", Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] 
bool AddPOI(string POICTG, string Name, string Description, string BestTimetoVisit, string TimeFrom, string TimeTo, string Address, string Contact_No, string Lattitude, string Longitude, string Altitude, string Accuracy, string Image, string Video_URL, string Active_Inactive_Flag);
```

Comment: Please do post on what exception you get when trying to insert the video URL being passed as a parameter?

Comment: I am not getting any Exceptions. When I Run that wcf by adding "-" It is moving to Code (known by adding Break Point). If I add Path then its not going to code.

Comment: Can you please post some sample code on how your WCF service looks? Also when passing the video URL does the insert happen into the DB and if so then how is the value getting saved as? Please post the difference that you observe when passing the video URL and without the "\"

Comment: [OperationContract()]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddPOI/{POICTG}/{Name}/{Description}/{BestTimetoVisit}/{TimeFrom}/{TimeTo}/{Address}/{Contact_No}/{Lattitude}/{Longitude}/{Altitude}/{Accuracy}/{Image}/{Video_URL}/{Active_Inactive_Flag}", Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool AddPOI(string POICTG, string Name, string Description, string BestTimetoVisit, string TimeFrom, string TimeTo, string Address, string Contact_No, string Lattitude, string Longitude, string Altitude, string Accuracy, string Image, string Video_URL, string Active_Inactive_Flag);

Comment: This is the code I am Using I am passing the Video URL as parameter Here

Comment: In your case you are trying to perform a add resource operation via REST seeing your code. Rather than performing a GET you need to perform a POST operation when adding items. Since you defined the method with GET the value of video_url param would cause problems. Try to encode your video URL param on the client side and then decode on server after reading the param. Best practise would be to change it to POST operation and wrap all the different parameters to a simple object.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. If I use POST Instead of Get then it is not going to execute in Browser. If I Use POST And running it in FIDDLER Its Showing error. I am Not getting Where is that error. thank you

Comment: Please post your raw request that you are using to post from Fiddler in your question so that we can know on where the problem is?

Comment: Here is the code which I am Adding to fiddler {
"POICTG":"1",
"Name":"Hello",
"Description":"Hi, How are you",
"BestTimetoVisit":"Jan",
"TimeFrom":"06-12-2015",
"TimeTo":"06-13-2015",
"Address":"ABC",
"Contact_No":"9966555522",
"Lattitude":"12.2315332",
"Longitude":"12.356465",
"Altitude":"2535",
"Accuracy":"2365",
"Image":"-",
"Video_URL":"-",
"Active_Inactive_Flag":"1",
"AddUser":"1"
}

Answer (score 0):

Service :

```
[OperationContract()]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AddPOI", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
bool AddPOI(POIObject objPOIObject);

    [DataContract]
    public class POIObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string POICTG { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string BestTimeToVisit{ get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TimeFrom { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TimeTo { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Contact_No { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Lattitude { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Altitude { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Accuracy { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Image { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Video_URL { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Active_Inactive_Flag { get; set; }

}
```

Now my raw request from Fiddler looks as below:

```
POST http://localhost/XMLService/AddPOI HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
content-type: application/json
Host: localhost:85
Content-Length: 361


 { "POICTG":"1", "Name":"Hello", "Description":"Hi, How are you", "BestTimetoVisit":"Jan", "TimeFrom":"06-12-2015", "TimeTo":"06-13-2015", "Address":"ABC", "Contact_No":"9966555522", "Lattitude":"12.2315332", "Longitude":"12.356465", "Altitude":"2535", "Accuracy":"2365", "Image":"image.png", "Video_URL":"http://www.google.com", "Active_Inactive_Flag":"1" }
```

The response is below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 4
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=kz1wx05h4lylpprrxplokl2t; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Date: Mon, 27 Apr 2015 11:36:12 GMT

true
```

I have wrapped all the parameters into a simple class object and then performing a post. Hope that helps

Comment: I am doing the same as you did. But I am facing the same problem. I think there is problem in assigning the object data to entity in the application. Please tell me how to assign the object data to entity through which I have to pass value to Query to execute.

Comment: What does "assigning the object data to entity in the application" it mean? If you get a 200 response back then your service is all working fine

Comment: Yup I got.... thank you.... Now When I am running from fiddler it is running but If I am passing the value through Angular Js Its showing "Method not allowed" Why is it so.....??????

Comment: Can you post on how your calling code from angularjs looks like. Also do capture the request in fiddler when the call from angularjs is made and compare it with the one that works from fiddler to know what is the problem

Comment: this.post = function (Poi) {
         var request = $http({
             //method: "POST",
             //url: "http://IP/TIS/Service1.svc/AddPOI",
             //data: Poi
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://IP/TIS/Service1.svc/AddPOI",
     data: Poi,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
         });
        return request;
     }

Comment: This is the code I am using for passing object through Angular Js. And when I submit ma details. And Inspecting the browser I am getting "Method Not Allowed Error"

Comment: Can you see your request in Fiddler.(Keep fiddler running when the request is being made from Angularjs) and then check the raw request

Comment: Please capture the raw request that is being posted from your android app and paste it here on your question to see what is causing the problem

Comment: var headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
   };

         var request = $http({
             method: "POST",
     url: "http://IPAddr/TIS/webservices/Service1.svc/AddPOI",
     data: Poi,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      headers: headers

         });
        return request;
     }                                                                                           I AM USING THIS CODE FOR ANGULARJS

Comment: @Niveditapatil : We need the raw request that is available in Fiddler. You have already posted the code that is used in your AngularJS app.

Comment: OPTIONS http://IP/TIS/webservices/Service1.svc/AddPOI HTTP/1.1
Host: IP
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://evil.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8080/AdminPanel/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

Comment: Do you see the service page when you browse to "IP/TIS/webservices/Service1.svc/AddPOI"? I guess your URL must be something like "http://IP/TIS/webservices/Service1.svc/AddPOI"

Comment: yaa its like this.....                                                                                             http://IP/WebServices/Service1.svc/AddPOI